# Issue with hiding div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Clicking on one of the navitem classes should hide the div with ID "hammenu"; however it doesn't hide.  The CSS does have the display set to "flex" and I tested that condition.  Still does not want to hide.  Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hammenucntr").click(function(e) {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $("#hammenu").css({
      "left": (pos.left + 20) + "px"
    }).show();
  })
  $(".navitem").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#hammenu")){ 
        $("#hammenu").hide();
      }
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div id="navm">
    <div class="hammenucntr">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      <div id="hammenu" class="navmenucntr">
        <div class="navitem">Home</div>
        <div class="navitem">Test 1</div>
        <div class="navitem">Test 2</div>
        <div class="navitem">Test 3</div>
        <div class="navitem">Test 4</div>
        <div class="navitem">Test 5</div>
        <div class="navitem">Test 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

UPDATE:
Ok this question started out as a complete train wreck.  I created a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.  I apologize for trying to hurry through asking a question.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spsimmons64/Lccze318/5/)

Comment: `if ($("#hammenu){ ` - missing closing `"` there.

Comment: You have some pretty obvious syntax issues here. I'd suggest always checking the console when some JS code doesn't work as expected. I've edited your question to include an executable snippet which should make the issues easier to see

Comment: I corrected the conditional issue I believe you are referring to.  Console shows nothing with clicking on a navitem.

Comment: @CBroe - Itchy trigger finger on first post.  Edit has been made to correct.  Issue still  lingering.

Comment: Then please edit question, to reflect current/actual code. Plus, make the whole thing into a [mcve], please, so that we can see what is actually going on.

Comment: (And why would you need to position the menu 20px to the left of where it currently is, each time you show it? Why is it not in _that_ position to begin with, in its hidden state already?)

Comment: `if ($("#hammenu){` missing the closing parentheses as well as the closing quotation mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first click handler $(".hammenucntr").click catch it before $(".navitem").click handler, cause .navitem is child of .hammenucntr. You should use e.stopPropagation() in second handler to stop bubbling event to its parent.

more about event phases: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing